# Why can't I see comment while streaming

Tags: ps4

[image].   I have been having trouble reading comments while streaming it just start doing this I haven't messed with anything in my settings to cause this if anyone knows that would be great!!

Answer (score 1):

First I would check your streaming options:
To view all comments, press the SHARE button and then select [Broadcast Settings] > [View Comments]. To enable your system to speak the comments, select [Broadcast Settings] > [Advanced Settings] > [Comments to Speech], and then select the checkbox for [Enable Comments to Speech].
Via: http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/share/broadcast.html

If that doesn't work I would check your settings in twitch but as far as I know there isn't a way to disable it there to get that message on your screen but there could be a new setting that would.